# Firebase + Flutterflow

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

I have a subcollection in FlutterFlow under users called "comments" and another "replies".

For each reply, I assign the comment ID in a Backend Query, this ends up creating an index in Firebase.

In a hypothetical situation, will Firebase reads count all documents or just the ones returned from the index?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase reads count only the documents that are retrieved as a result of the query or operation executed. When you perform a query in Firebase Firestore, it fetches only the documents that match the query criteria, not all documents in the collection.